# Macro in Excel with changeable path

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 files my Access DB **AHT_Tenure.accdb** and my Excel file with a Macro to run a query on the *.accdb*. The macro is the following:

```
Sub AHT_Tenure()
Dim A As Object
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set A = CreateObject("Access.Application")
A.Visible = False
A.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\Users\gustavo.chi\Documents\AHT_tenure\AHT_Tenure.accdb")
With A.CurrentDB.QueryDefs("Q_AHT_Tenure_combine")
   .Execute
   MsgBox .RecordsAffected
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

As you can see the path is **C:\Users\gustavo.chi\Documents\AHT_tenure\AHT_Tenure.accdb** I always keep both files in the Folder called **\AHT_tenure** How do I edit the macro so I can move the path of the folder and the macro will still work? I want to have the folder with the files in a USB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I always keep both files in the Folder called \AHT_tenure

Try this

```
A.OpenCurrentDatabase ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AHT_Tenure.accdb"
```

**Explanation**: `ThisWorkbook.Path` will give you `"C:\Users\gustavo.chi\Documents\AHT_tenure"` or the path of whatever location that excel file is.